How do I return JSON from ASP.NET Core 8 MVC controller method?
The following does not return a response. I get the same result if I change Ok() to Created(). If I change it to BadRequest(), it returns JSON as expected. What am I doing wrong?
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Test()
{
    return Ok(new { Test = "Value" });
}

Here is my Program.cs:
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using RisingTide.Center.Data;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddDbContext<RisingTideCenterContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("RisingTideCenterContext") ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("Connection string 'RisingTideCenterContext' not found.")));

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();


It's quite odd, usually with Ok() should be able to return JSON response. Maybe you can share your Program.cs to see how you configure the application.

@YongShun I added the Program.cs to the question.

Looks fine, can I know how you call the mentioned API and obtain the value? Also, did you try working with Postman to send request, and encounter the same issue?

@AnthonyMallgren: Run project, open the Windows command prompt and enter curl -X POST "https://localport:your_port/Home/Test. What is the output?

The request is working through Postman and curl. I was trying to view the request through Chrome DevTools, which was showing no response. Also, I was using the wrong case in jQuery due to the first letter of the variable being changed to lower case in the response. I'm not sure if anyone would like to put an answer. Thank you for helping me out with this issue. I really appreciate it.

I also write the test demo to and it works inside the postman and curl, do you have other issue now?

No, all good here. Thank you!
